# Linq query with Contains having null value

Tags: c#, linq

```
var qry = from _Cr in _er.Courses 
          from _R in _er.ResultsHeaders  
          where  _R.Studentid == studentid 
          && !_Cr.CourseID.Contains( _R.CourseID )
          select new Obj_getCourses
          {
              Courseid = _Cr.CourseID,
              CourseName = _Cr.CourseName 
          };
```

_er.CoursesTable have 4 values in it and  _er.ResultsHeader table is empty. I was expecting 4 values from query but the query is not returning any Value. This is the query I am trying to write in LINQ.

```
Select * \
from Courses \
where courseid not in (Select courseid from ResultsHeader where studentid = 123);
```

Help require.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To get SQL you posted, you should try following query:

```
var qry = from _Cr in _er.Courses 
          where !_er.ResultsHeader.Where(r => r.StudentId == studentId)
                                  .Select(r => r.CourseID)
                                  .Contains(_Cr.CourseID)
          select new Obj_getCourses
          {
              Courseid = _Cr.CourseID,
              CourseName = _Cr.CourseName 
          };
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you your desired results. I have written it in C# statement style so hopefully that having it is LINQ style was not a pre-requisite...

```
var qry = _er.Courses
    .Where( c => !c.CourseID.Contains(_er.ResultsHeader
        .Where( r => r.StudentID == 123)
        .Select(r => r.CourseID)
    )
    .Select(c => new Obj_getCourses 
    {
        Courseid = c.CourseID,
        Coursename = c.CourseName
    });
```